# Change Buttom Image Out of onClick Android

Tags: java, android, onclick

Hello every thing for change Button change image I found, was change image when you clicking on button like this

```
imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

             ImageButton aButton = (ImageButton)v;
             aButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
            }
        });
//I wanna change button image here
```

How can I change image source out of "on click" function?

Comment: instead of using `aButton` simply use `imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);`

Comment: what do you mean by `out of "on click" function` ?

Comment: //I wanna change button image here (Question edited)

Comment: Just put it 'here' : imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is confusing but to do what you want your code should be the following:

```
imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
             ImageButton aButton = (ImageButton)v;
             aButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
        }
});
imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
```

This will set your buttons image resource to image2 - but change to image1 when it is clicked.

Comment: can use on touch listener and use Action down to set image 1 and action up to set default. Other option is to use a selector.

Answer (score 1):

i think you want selector means when you press button then its background changed and when we relieve then it will get previous image.

for this you will selector:

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/

i hope, it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that imageButton is global variable inside parent class

```
imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

             imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
// This will change the Image Button to use image2
imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

             imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
            }
        });
```

However i must ask why you need to change imageButton to image2 in the code at the place that you asked? You can simply achieve this in xml.